# Query from to date with php in mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql

I have a date field in a mysql table formatted like this: Y-m-d.

I want to export every post that has a date between $fromDate and all the way to $toDate
I am sure its easy but now i am totaly blocked from ideas.

I am using codeigniter if that helps.

Best Regards
Audun

Comment: What format are `$fromDate` and `$toDate` in?

Comment: they are like this $toDate = $this->input->post('toDate'); that gives Y-m-d like 2009-03-23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building a query similar to this and passing it to mysql_query (assuming your date format in $fromDate and $toDate match the date format of your mysql column)

```
<?

$query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In CodeIgniter documentation about Active Record at http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html, there is a sub-section with title "$this->db->where();".

You can use comparison signs (like !=, <, >, <= and >=) just after the name of the column on which condition(s) is checked. For instance :
`$this->db->where('id <', $id);`

```
$array = array('name !=' => $name, 'id <' => $id, 'date >' => $date);
$this->db->where($array);
```